# TypeError with $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

Am trying to post a data to the server but when am run my code it shows me a error like this...

TypeError: Cannot create property 'method' on string '{"email":"unkonw@gmail.com","role":"2","home":"A0110"}'

please help me how to clear this error and my controller program is...

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('register', function ($scope, $http, transformRequestAsFormPost) {

    $scope.send = function register() {
        alert("test");
        $http.post("http://52.77.16.197:8000/subscribe/user",
                   transformRequest = transformRequestAsFormPost,
                   data = JSON.stringify( {email : $scope.email, role: $scope.role, home: $scope.home }))
            .success(function (response) {
                alert("hi");
                $scope.persons = data;
            }).error(function (response) {
                if (response.message == "already_subscribed") {
                    alert("already_subscribed");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
    }

});
```

and my html code is...

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="register" id="reg">
        <ul>
            <h2> Id and roles :</h2>
            <li ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index">
            {{ person.email + ' : ' + person.role + ' : ' + person.home }} 
            </li>
        </ul>

        <input type="email" ng-model="email"  />
        <br />

        <input type="text" ng-model= "role"  />
 <br />
               <input type="text" ng-model= "home" />
        <br />
         <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="register()" /><br />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is transformRequestAsFormPost  ? i see there is problem with the JSON data what is the exact  json structure you have to post ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is written wrong

```
$scope.register = function() 
{}
```

Comment: but i written a function for send already.                                             function register() {
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("reg")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.send();
    });
}

Comment: From where send() is called?

Comment: @Paresh Gami yes that is one more Point missing !!

Comment: What other you missing?

Comment: other than this nothing i missed

Answer (score 0):

Your `$http` call parameters are incorrect

```
$http.post("http://52.77.16.197:8000/subscribe/user", 
            transformRequest = transformRequestAsFormPost,
            data = JSON.stringify( {email : $scope.email,
                                    role: $scope.role,
                                    home: $scope.home
                                  }
                                 )
          )
```

From the Docs:

> ### post(url, data, [config]);<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)</sup>
>
> Shortcut method to perform POST request.
>
> Parameters
>
> - url string   Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request
> - data * Request content
> - config (optional) Optional configuration object

Data should the second parameter and config the third parameter.

The error message:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'method' on string '{"email":"unkonw@gmail.com","role":"2","home":"A0110"}'

The `$http` service doesn't like the third parameter.

The code shows many other problems, too lengthy to answer here.